# Haxelib 32bit is not a valid win32 program

Tags: winapi, windows-xp, haxe, stencyl

I recently started using stencyl and when I tried to compile for the first time I got the error haxelib is not a valid win32 application (I'm using a Windows XP dinosaur that is seemingly no longer internet capable and down a memory unit) I retried a few times then went about the task of finding a compatible version of haxe every version I found claimed to be winxp compatible and each time I downloaded, transferred to the computer in question, and Extracted I was presented with the same files. And while opening haxe.exe in any of themopens a command prompt style window (presumably expected behavior), haxelib.exe just throws the same error

Edit:

I did come across one post about the reverse happening somewhere but nothing there helped

Comment: You could download previous haxe version archive, take and replace haxelib.exe from it. As I remember haxelib from 3.1.3 should work

Comment: I actually just logged on to say that switching stencyl build 9300 (rather than 10300) solved the issue and I'll have to deal with not having any of the features in the newest version

Answer (score -1):

After wack-a-moleing a lot of issues I eventually decided to use an older version of stencyl and it works fine I just have to downgrade my project version I recommend this solution to anyone interested in developing games on windows XP as in my experience standard IDEs like netbeans use too much ram to run effectively on older computers.

Edit:

Specifically the last 3.x build (9300)